# Failing PHPUnit tests in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, composer-php, homestead

I have a fresh clone of `laravel/framework:master` running on a Homestead VM (on Mac host). I installed the dependencies (`composer install` - also `composer update`). When I run the tests I get

> ```
> There were 2 failures:
>
>  1) FilesystemTest::testIsReadable Failed asserting that true is false.
>
>  /home/vagrant/Code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/tests/Filesystem/FilesystemTest.php:305
>
>  2) ValidationValidatorTest::testValidateActiveUrl Failed asserting that false is true.
>
>  /home/vagrant/Code/project/vendor/laravel/framework/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php:1825
> ```

---

> ```
> $ php -v
> PHP 7.1.0-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>     with Zend OPcache v7.1.0-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
>     with blackfire v1.14.1~linux-x64-non_zts71, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.
>
> $ phpunit --version
> PHPUnit 5.7.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
> ```

Am I missing something?

---

#### Update

I answered my own question with the workarounds I found for these problems,  although I don't fully understand them. Particularly I don't know if these issues were somehow special to my setup or instead are common and to be expected, in which case I wonder why the default Homestead configuration doesn't address them.

I'm leaving the question open for a while, in case anyone wants to explain or comment.

Comment: That looks like a directory does not have read/write permissions for the user PHP runs as.

Comment: @JohnJoseph actually, the test that fails expects `isReadable` to be false. Also, the other failing test is not about permissions (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was an exception being thrown on `dns_get_record` (called in `active_url` validation). Thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/409) I learnt that setting the `natdnshostresolver` option to "off" could solve it for me.

On the first failing test, after `chmod 000` a file, the assertion expected the file not to be readable. But it always stayed readable. It then occurred to me that I was doing the tests on a folder which was synced on the host machine. (Maybe it can't remove the read permission there?). I tried again from a non-synced folder and the test passed.